# $pull object from embedded array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have structure:

```
{
  items: [{
    //...some object fields
    tags: [
      {  _id: 1,
         name: 'Tag 1'  
      },
      {  _id: 2,
         name: 'Tag 2'  
      },
    ]}, 
  {...}
 , ...
]
}
```

How do I pull tag that has _id 1 for example? **Also** I need to do this on multiple documents, so it needs to be `.updateMany()`.

I tried like so but it won't update:

```
    await Rankings.RankingData.updateMany(
      { 'items.tags': { $elemMatch: { _id: id } } },
      { $pull: { 'items.$[item].tags': { $elemMatch: { _id: id } } } },
      { multi: true, arrayFilters: [{ 'item.tags': { $elemMatch: { _id: id } } }] },
    );
```

I succeed on fetching the right documents with the query, so its the problem of $pull or arrayFilters...? Note again I need to pull a tag from items array, not the whole item!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, use the positional operator `$` to refer to the element in the items array that satisfied the condition in the filter.

$pull already assumes that all of its criteria must be matched by a the same array element, os $elemMatch is not necessary when filtering the array.  It is also not required when there is only 1 criterion in the filter:

```
 await Rankings.RankingData.updateMany(
      { 'items.tags': { _id: id }  },
      { $pull: { 'items.$.tags': { _id: id }  } },
      { multi: true},
    );
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3stMmOblYw-)